# What is the best way to write multiple tcp streams to individual files?

Tags: go

I have multiple binary incoming tcp streams, arriving at random times continually.  I want to write each of them to individual files.  The files should contain everything from the initial open of a connection until the remote client closes the connection.

I have this below, and it seems to work, but is this an efficient way of doing so?

```
//error handling to be added later

func main() {

    listen, _ := net.Listen("tcp4", ":8080")
    defer listen.Close()

    for {
        connection, _ := listen.Accept()
        defer connection.Close()

        //"myfile.dat" to be replaced later with variable creating unique names
        go handleConnection(connection, "myfile.dat")
    }
}

func handleConnection(connection net.Conn, myFile string) {

    outputFile, _ := os.Create(myFile)
    defer outputFile.Close()
    fileWriter := bufio.NewWriter(outputFile)

    for {
        serverConnReader := bufio.NewReader(connection)
        io.Copy(fileWriter, serverConnReader)
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes on the code:

- Handle errors.
- `defer connection.Close()` in `handleConnection`. Otherwise, the connection will not be closed until the program terminates.
- Move the two lines of code in the `handleConnection` out of the for loop and discard the for loop. The loop is not doing anything.
- Add `defer fileWriter.Flush()` to flush any last bit of data buffered in the writer (but see next point).
- Ask the file to copy from the connection directly.

Here's the code:

```
func main() {

    listen, err := net.Listen("tcp4", ":8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer listen.Close()

    for {
        connection, err := listen.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        go handleConnection(connection, "myfile.dat")
    }
}

func handleConnection(connection net.Conn, myFile string) {
    defer connection.Close()
    outputFile, err := os.Create(myFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer outputFile.Close()
    _, err = outputFile.ReadFrom(connection)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to close the file.